# Request is missing required authentication credential

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, postman

I am trying to send FCM message through POSTMAN. I have added the server key, the one from cloud messaging in settings of firebase console.

[image]

[image: error]

What is missing here?

Answer (score 4):

The example in the  documentation for [authorizing HTTP v1 send requests](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/auth-server#authorize_http_v1_send_requests) shows the Authorization header value starts with `Bearer` not `key=`:

```
headers: {
  'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + accessToken
}
```

Comment: If we want to send the notifications from Postman, then how to generate the accessToken that can be used long time ?

Answer (score 0):

You should change format of you requests.

More info here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/send-message#send_messages_using_the_legacy_app_server_protocols

> If you prefer to use the legacy protocols, build message requests as shown in this section. Keep in mind that, if you are sending to multiple platforms via HTTP, the v1 protocol can simplify your message requests.

**HTTP POST request**

```
https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send
Content-Type:application/json
Authorization:key=AIzaSyZ-1u...0GBYzPu7Udno5aA

{ "data": {
    "score": "5x1",
    "time": "15:10"
  },
  "to" : "bk3RNwTe3H0:CI2k_HHwgIpoDKCIZvvDMExUdFQ3P1..."
}
```

Answer (score -4):

Use following:

link: https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send

"Authorization" "key=" + server key

Body

```
{ 
    "to" : "/topics/carriers",
    "notification" : {
        "body" : "This message came from Server!",
        "title" : "FROM POSTMAN"
    }
}
```

for me this is the only configuration that works