# Firestore Request is missing required authentication credential

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore

I am still in the learning phase of firestore and have been testing away all day with no issues until 30 minutes ago when I am now getting this message in postman and also on my test app.

I am using the Firestore Rest API if that makes any difference

Request is missing required authentication credential.

The error message is plain enough but I am at a loss as to how to fix it.

Comment: Have you added the auth header in request? or have you updated your security rules recently and now the queries require auth header?

Comment: My rules are still at default
allow read, write: if
          request.time < timestamp.date(2021, 10, 21);

How do I add the auth header

Comment: You need to add an `Authorization` header containing Firebase auth ID Token. Can you try that/

Comment: Looking project settings, I have an API Key, would this be it. ?

Comment: No, an access token from Firebase auth. Check [this documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/use-rest-api#authenticating_with_an_access_token)

Comment: I suggest you to check this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48723768/request-is-missing-required-authentication-credential) in which they discuss the same issue that you're facing.